# Why is cell value showing as empty when in loop but populated when directly referenced?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I'm trying to read in data from separate matrices and place them into a single matrix, but I'm having problems with adding chars into my cell array.

The data that I'm having difficulties with comprises of a column of character codes that represent a classification. For example 'J', 'MS1', 'FS1', 'FA1'...

When adding it to a new cell the code 'J' would work but all the other codes would show as '1×1 cell array {0×0 char}'.

Here I loop through my data sets to get he information I need into one mat.

Loop through dataset:

```
krillinfo1 = {'J','MA1','J','FA1'};
for n=1:4
        krillinfo1(1,n) %this line is where print out the data for debugging

        temp={krillinfo1(1,n)};
        krillvectors(n,:) = temp;
end
```

When outputting krillinfo1(1,4), it shows the expected format:

```
ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {'FA2'}
```

But when krillinfo1(1,n) is printed from my loop above it becomes:

```
ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {0×0 char}
```

For context My krillinfo1(1,n) column looks like this:
J,
J,
J,
FA1,
J,
J,
J,
J,
FS1,
J,
etc.

Comment: "But when I output krillinfo1(n,4), krillinfo1(36,4) becomes" This makes no sense. How do you output `krillinfo1(n,4)`? Please read [mcve], then edit your question accordingly. Try to make a short script that shows this issue, that I can copy-paste into my MATLAB terminal and see what you see. That is the best way for anyone to be able to point out what is going on. Otherwise there will always be uncertainties in the communication. Describing what you did is not nearly as good as showing what you did.

Comment: I still don't see how this would happen. The issue is likely elsewhere in your code. Please, read [mcve] as I asked above, and post a script that I can copy-paste to run exactly the same thing you are running. Reduce the size of the input, create artificial data, remove parts of your program, make it all as small as possible while still showing this cell magically emptying. Also, I bet you'll find your own error while doing that, it's a great debugging trick! :)

Comment: Thank you for both your feedback. Ive made a smaller version of the code and it works just fine, so I think you may be right Cris about my code being incorrect somewhere else.

Comment: Take the code with the problem, and remove bits and pieces, run it every time you make a change to make sure the issue is still there. When you remove something and the issue goes away, put that bit back, and continue removing other stuff. Eventually you'll have the smallest bit of code that reproduces the problem. Likely you'll understand much better what the problem is by this time.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will have another look!